# Making git submodules track branch after shallow initialization

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose I initialize shallow-submodules with:

`git clone --depth 1 --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodules https://github.com/vishvAsa/jyotiSham.git`

I cannot then make submodules track the remote branch (`cd content; git checkout content`). `error: pathspec 'content' did not match any file(s) known to git`

So, in intellij IDE, the submodule shows up as "detached head", which then makes certain GUI-based operations cumbersome (checking in changes within submodules, updating submodules).

[image: Example from a different but similar repo]

Is there any way to track the remote branch without recloning? Alternatively, is there a simple way to make all submodules non-shallow?

Comment: To run any arbitrary shell command in all submodules, use `git submodule foreach`. If that command is `git fetch --unshallow`, that will un-shallow that particular Git repository.

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout -b content
```

worked.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?